# Add global prefix for Django URLs

Tags: django

Instead of using subdomains I would like to add subfolders like:

**burger.domain.com** -> **domain.com/organization/burger/**

is there any way to add `/organization/<name:str>/` globaly?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you have a reverse proxy server like NGINX/Apache, you can update the `X-Script-Name`. For example in `NGINX`:

```
location /organization {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /organization;
}
```

In that way, django will be served at path `/organization`(as per configuration of `X-Script-Name`). You can also checkout this [`blog`](https://integricho.github.io/2014/02/22/running-django-on-a-subpath/) for more information regarding deploying django with Apache.

But, if you don't have such reverse proxy server, then you can use [**`FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#force-script-name). In django settings add the following line:

```
FORCE_SCRIPT_NAME = '/organization'
```